# How to get mime file type in android

Tags: android

I want to know how to get mime file type

```
@Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{
    boolean error = false; 
    FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
    String mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(url);


if(mimeType.equals("text/html") || mimeType.equals("application/xhtml+xml"))
{
    webview.loadUrl(url);
    return true;

}
}
```

but its not working , Please any body help me on this

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String getMimeType(String url)
{
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

The url can be a file path or a Stable Web URL.

Comment: i used your code and doing this

    if(getMimeType(url).equals("text/html") || getMimeType(url).equals("application/xhtml+xml")) {     webview.loadUrl(url); return true;

}
but still app crashing on time of click

Comment: `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)` `{ boolean error = false; //FileNameMap fileNameMap =` `URLConnection.getFileNameMap(); //String mimeType =` `fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(url); String type = null; String` `extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url); if (extension` `!= null) { MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton(); type =` `mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension); }` `if(type.equals("text/html") || type.equals("application/xhtml+xml"))` `{ webview.loadUrl(url); return true; } } `
its crashing my app

Comment: Have you posted the stacktrace.